# Set KUBECONFIG environment variable dynamically

Tags: bash, shell, find

I am quite new to Bash and working on multiple kubernetes cluster. I wanted some kind of utility wherein I can set my KUBECONFIG variable dynamically as I work on multiple clusters. My kubeconfig file lies in multiple folders. What I want is to find all the kubeconfig files , get the paths and concatenate the paths with colon , set it to KUBECONFIG variable and export it in bashrc file.

I know pieces of command but not able to frame full code.

```
find /Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/ -name kubeconfig.yaml -exec echo {} \;
```

I want to concatenate the output of find command and set my KUBECONFIG. like this "

`export KUBECONFIG=/Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/work2/kubeconfigs/scdc1-staging-hrwork-dev/kubeconfig.yaml:/Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/work2/kubeconfigs/scdc2-prod-hrwork-uat/kubeconfig.yaml:/Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/work2/kubeconfigs/scdc2-prod-hrwork/kubeconfig.yaml` "

Comment: if you have written pieces of code you can share it here so others get idea what exactly you want and which way.

Comment: find /Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/ -name kubeconfig.yaml -exec  echo {} \; ...... I want to concatenate the output of find command and set my KUBECONFIG. like this " export KUBECONFIG=/Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/work2/kubeconfigs/scdc1-staging-hrwork-dev/kubeconfig.yaml:/Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/work2/kubeconfigs/scdc2-prod-hrwork-uat/kubeconfig.yaml:/Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/work2/kubeconfigs/scdc2-prod-hrwork/kubeconfig.yaml 
"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
export KUBECONFIG=$(for i in $(find /Users/anandabhishe/gitlab/ -iname 'kubeconfig.yaml') ; do echo -n ":$i"; done | cut -c 2-)
```

Comment: `export KUBECONFIG=$(for YAML in $(find ${HOME}/.kube -name '*.yaml') ; do echo -n ":${YAML}"; done)`

Comment: https://direnv.net/ is a great tool to solve these things, you can have for a directory different enviornment variables with different values.